# How to completely delete OAuth application from GitHub organization?

Tags: github, github-organizations

Going to `https://github.com/organizations/<YOUR_ORGANIZATION_NAME>/settings/oauth_application_policy`, titled **Third-party application access policy** you can "Grant" or "Deny" access to third party applications.
But what actions do you need to take to completely remove an item from that page?

Assume in this case I am the account that "granted" the access or "requested" that access be granted. But a solution that allows an organization owner to do this regardless would be preferable.

Comment: I don't think that's something you can do. Requests to gain access to repositories isn't initiated from within GitHub; that happens externally.

Comment: I have been looking into this and think there is no way in the UI to do it.

Comment: @mljrg do you know of a cli/windows app way of doing it? Or you mean it only happens administratively when malicious apps are reported to GitHub humans?

Comment: I don't understand your last question, but I am not aware of any tool to do it. This is something internal to GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are asking the way to revoke access to your github account by a 3rd party application

> *Github.com/settings/Applications/Authorized OAuthApps*

Choose **revoke** access.

Comment: Nah, I am asking how to make it as if it never asked in the first place. (At least from UX viewpoint)

Comment: Please can you be more specific about the question , provide any snapshot ,so it will be a bit more helpful to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't completely remove a third-party app from your organization. **Deny Access** is the only thing you can do, it completely removes access to the app from your organization which means the app can no longer see any of your private repositories in that organization but the app will still be shown in your organization's third-app list as denied.

Comment: Does anyone know why?